# What is an application package?

Tags: flutter

https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/private-files this guide mentions not to commit the pubspec.lock file "except for application package". What exactly is an application package? How can I distinguish if I should or shouldn't commit this file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to avoid unwanted files , packages committing to the git
so the official flutter repo has given [gitignore](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/.gitignore) file you can use. Add this `.gitignore` file to the root of the project.

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.lock
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# Visual Studio Code related
.classpath
.project
.settings/
.vscode/

# Flutter repo-specific
/bin/cache/
/bin/internal/bootstrap.bat
/bin/internal/bootstrap.sh
/bin/mingit/
/dev/benchmarks/mega_gallery/
/dev/bots/.recipe_deps
/dev/bots/android_tools/
/dev/devicelab/ABresults*.json
/dev/docs/doc/
/dev/docs/flutter.docs.zip
/dev/docs/lib/
/dev/docs/pubspec.yaml
/dev/integration_tests/**/xcuserdata
/dev/integration_tests/**/Pods
/packages/flutter/coverage/
version
analysis_benchmark.json

# packages file containing multi-root paths
.packages.generated

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
**/generated_plugin_registrant.dart
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
build/
flutter_*.png
linked_*.ds
unlinked.ds
unlinked_spec.ds

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
.gradle/
**/android/captures/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
**/android/key.properties
*.jks

# iOS/XCode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.moved-aside
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/**/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/*sync/
**/ios/**/.sconsign.dblite
**/ios/**/.tags*
**/ios/**/.vagrant/
**/ios/**/DerivedData/
**/ios/**/Icon?
**/ios/**/Pods/
**/ios/**/.symlinks/
**/ios/**/profile
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
**/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
**/ios/Flutter/ephemeral
**/ios/Flutter/app.flx
**/ios/Flutter/app.zip
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh
**/ios/ServiceDefinitions.json
**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

# macOS
**/Flutter/ephemeral/
**/Pods/
**/macos/Flutter/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.swift
**/macos/Flutter/ephemeral
**/xcuserdata/

# Windows
**/windows/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
**/windows/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.h
**/windows/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake

# Linux
**/linux/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
**/linux/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.h
**/linux/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake

# Coverage
coverage/

# Symbols
app.*.symbols

# Exceptions to above rules.
!**/ios/**/default.mode1v3
!**/ios/**/default.mode2v3
!**/ios/**/default.pbxuser
!**/ios/**/default.perspectivev3
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages
!/dev/ci/**/Gemfile.lock
```